# remove item from cart for a given product id

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I am new in magento i have tried to remove items in cart when call this event checkout_cart_product_add_after when i try this code nothing can doing. any body help me. thanks.

```
$myProductId=20;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($myProductId);
$quote =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
if ($cartItems) {  $quote->removeItem($cartItems->getId())->save();}
```

Answer (score 6):

The ItemId (ID of an item in the cart) is not the same as the ProductId of the product it represents. Try iterating through the items in the cart until you find the one with the ProductId you want to remove:

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId) {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        break;
    }
}
```

Please try as described above.

Comment: i am trying this is work fine but only remove first product from cart. actually i am working in wish list when customer press Add All to cart button the event call the observer function and only those product is removed which i want.

Comment: for this you need to apply more checks in if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId) { where you can for example pass productid to the observer.

Comment: when i pass array of those productids which i want to remove then the above code will work? but didn't know how i pass array of produtids. help me.

Comment: Farman please take a look here to pass array to observer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277121/return-data-back-to-dispatcher-from-event-observer-in-magento

Comment: dear i cant pass array to observer seeing my code in observer echo "<pre>";
$myProductId = array_keys($data);//array of productids
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->getProduct()->getId(), $myProductId) ) {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        break;
    }
}

Comment: it is removinf only first product due to break in the last line.

Comment: please remove break altogether from the code, so that the loop execute completely, deleting all matching products.

Answer (score 1):

Below code work for me you can try this you can call this function using ajax or post method put this function inside your controller and call it. pass the customer id and product it to it

```
public function removeCartAction()
{
    $productId = trim($_POST['productId']);
    $customer  = trim($_POST['requesterId']);
    if ($customer) {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getWebsite(true)->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStoreId();
        // get quote table cart detail of all customer added 
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($storeId)->loadByCustomer($customer);        
        if ($quote) {
            $collection = $quote->getItemsCollection(false);
            if ($collection->count() > 0) {
                foreach( $collection as $item ) {
                    if ($item && $item->getId()) {
                        $quote->removeItem($item->getId());
                        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove item by specific item_id from cart(quote) you can use this:

```
         $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();

         $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
         $items = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
         foreach($items as $item):
         if($item->getItemId() == $id):
               $itemId = $item->getItemId();
               $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
               break;
         endif;
         endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute this you will get the output

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $_item) {
    if ($_item->getProductId() == $productId) {
            $_item->isDeleted(true);
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('This product cannot be added to shopping cart.');
        }
    }
```