# Call a function when product imported successfully in magento

Tags: magento

Hello I am importing products in magneto programatically using Advance import profile and I want to run re-index after the whole import is finished. I have tried digging the magento, But can't find any function that is being called after importing is finished...

I have found a file process.phtml that is calling ajax for each csv row /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/convert/profile

So I have created a file on the root and call it via ajax to import each row, But it created a deadlock in Mysql and import throws error SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get locked; try restarting transaction.

```
function reIndexData(){
                        var url = '<?php echo str_replace("index.php/","",Mage::getBaseUrl()); ?>';
                         new Ajax.Request(url+'reindex.php', {
                          method: "post",
                          parameters: 'data',
                          onSuccess: function(transport) {}
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: Have you create Different php file for advanced import profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with this path..
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert

You will find the file  ProfileController.php there is a function called batchFinishAction() 
which is getting called when import profile complete

Phew... Got it!! Thanks all for your kind help..

Answer (score 3):

There is an observer called

```
catalog_product_import_finish_before
```

This should allow you to re-index the DB every time a product is imported

Here is some information about Magento Observers:

**What is a Magento Observer?**

Observers allow you to see (observe) when a certain action happens in the program (for example, see when an item has been imported).

An Observer allows us to inject and run code once we see a certain action (such as a product being imported)

**How do I set up an Observer?**

See this question: [What is the correct way to set up an observer in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048458/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-up-an-observer-in-magento)

Answer (score 2):

You can also dispatch your custom event anywhere in Magento and call your method to for reIndex process.

For more details see these [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921057/custom-events-in-magento) And [Second](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-magento-events-customer-first-order/)